# error with irregularities in the loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an simple If loop. I have an button and I am calling several funtions behind this.

The Problem here is when I click the button, the function  thisworkbook.G70 is not getting executed properly.

I always get the result printed only for first 11 columns. Can anyone tell what would be the reason. ?

here is the code I am using,

```
Sub G1()
Dim i               As Long
Dim totalrows      As Long
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim DeltaDays       As Long
Set ws = Sheets("PSW")
totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
With ws
For i = 5 To totalrows
If .Cells(i, 27).Value = "" Then
.Cells(i, 28).Value = "N/A"
Else
DeltaDays = DateDiff("d", .Cells(i, 27).Value, .Cells(i, 23).Value)
If DeltaDays = 0 Then
.Cells(i, 28).Value = "G1 OK"
.Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(69, 139, 0)
ElseIf DeltaDays < 0 Then
.Cells(i, 28).Value = "G1 OK(R)"
.Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(127, 255, 0)
ElseIf DeltaDays > 0 Then
.Cells(i, 28).Value = "G1 NOK"
.Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
End If
Next i
End With
MsgBox ("G1 Mismatch found")
End Sub
```

If I am running this code, without using the button, then it is working properly.

With the button, it is not executing the complete code.

Can anyone tell how I could debug this error.

Comment: You can set breakpoints on the lines where you think something goes wrong. Run the function with and without clicking the button to see the difference.

Comment: where is the line with thisworkbook.G70?

Comment: I don't see thisworkbook.G70 -- which you seem to imply is connected to your button. Are you sure the button is connected to this code?

Comment: you `use `Set ws = Sheets("PSW")` to set the worksheet object, but on the following line you use `totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row` , which means you rely on the `ActiveSheet` object, it's safer if you use `totalrows = ws.Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: And could you post some sample data as well?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem seems to be with this line...

```
totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
```

Also always properly indent your code that makes it more readable.

Try it like this...

```
Sub G1()
Dim i               As Long
Dim totalrows      As Long
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim DeltaDays       As Long
Set ws = Sheets("PSW")    
With ws
    totalrows = .Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 5 To totalrows
        If .Cells(i, 27).Value = "" Then
            .Cells(i, 28).Value = "N/A"
        Else
            DeltaDays = DateDiff("d", .Cells(i, 27).Value, .Cells(i, 23).Value)
            If DeltaDays = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = "G1 OK"
                .Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(69, 139, 0)
            ElseIf DeltaDays < 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = "G1 OK(R)"
                .Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(127, 255, 0)
            ElseIf DeltaDays > 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = "G1 NOK"
                .Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
MsgBox ("G1 Mismatch found")
End Sub
```

Comment: this also dint work. I have an problem with my calling function I suspect. I have few sheets to visible/ For eg, shet1, sheet2, sheet3 and my G1 is to be printed in sheet psw. Immedietly after the xlsheetvisible function  I have call thisworkbook.G1, I suspect that it stays in sheet3 and skips this function